# PERMISSION_DENIED for BigQuery Storage API on Apache Beam 2.39.0 and DataFlow runner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have the following error for one of my DataFlow Jobs:

> 2022-06-15T16:12:27.365182607Z Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: BigQuery Storage API has not been used in project 770406736630 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/bigquerystorage.googleapis.com/overview?project=770406736630 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

The same code works fine with Apache Beam 2.38.0. I tested multiple times and this is not a temporary issues. The project number mentioned in the error (770406736630) is not mine.

Any idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this, and simply needed to re-authenticate with the gcp cli by running `gcloud auth application-default login`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I'm using Spring Cloud GCP and hadn't set the `spring.cloud.gcp.project-id` property, which I'm guessing makes the SDK or API use some default value.

I don't know how you've set up you environment, because you haven't specified, but look into how you can explicitly set the project id. You can get it from the dialog for selecting a project in GCP Console.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens for the latest Apache Beam SKD (2.41.0) when `BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STORAGE_WRITE_API` is used and destination does not specify the project name. For example `dataset.table` instead of `project-id:dataset.table`

This is the solution that worked for me:

```kotlin
    BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
        .to("project-id:dataset.table")
        .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STORAGE_WRITE_API)
```

For some reason the Apache Beam implementation for BigQuery Write Storage API does not handle this situation even though it works fine for `FILE_LOADS` method.

You may also receive a sightly different error for the latest Beam SDK.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException:
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: 
PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied: Consumer 'project:null' has been suspended.
```